# Does anyone know how to make straws for a hawaiian style hut or stall?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I want to make a stall in 3d like this one:

[image]

...and I don't know how to make straws or strings to make it look like that. I tried with hair but I don't understand it too well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links just to understand your question, use the tools on the site to upload images directly.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png). You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try hair particles, brush them a bit randomly and then use a 'particle instance' modifier to put another mesh on the hair particles, here's a rough attempt-
[image]

And here's the .blend to pull apart-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pljlpiel33jllt/StrawHairParticles.blend?dl=0

Use more emitters and more meshes to instance onto the hair, and go nuts 'combing' (particle edit mode) the hair, and you should be able to get way closer than my 5 minute attempt!